# Android crash while application loading (Unity3D 3.5.64f (latest))

Tags: android, mono, crash, unity-game-engine

I know this is Unity3D question and there are more specific stack/forum sites...
Pls see attached logcat log, is there anything which gives us any clue?

Unity Splash screen appears on device, but after a few seconds it crashes. This app was OK yesterday, I added some C# code textures etc.  I carefully examined the debug build logcat log. My code has not even a chance to run, the crash happens before...
Note: No Mono runtime exception in logcat log.

- It works fine in Unity editor, or windows standalone build.
- Again: It worked fine, with the same settings yesterday. More: The yesterday's backup sill working today, rebuild, deploy to the same device. This today's version (I1ve added textures, code etc) which is not working on the device.

See the log attached.

Don't know where to search toward... :-(
Thx for help

[Download logcat log file](http://forum.unity3d.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=39449&d=1350310564)

Comment: Did you try asking on http://answers.unity3d.com/ ? You say you know there are other sites, so why did you choose to post this here? It appears too localized for our site and you are unlikely to get a good answer here.

Comment: Of course I did. Actually that was my first try...